# How do I diagnose memory usage/leaks of drivers?

Tags: memory-leaks

I use Process Explorer for typical day-to-day process management, and I'm aware of Poolmon for monitoring pool leaks. Are there similar tools available for examining memory usage of drivers, and how are these tools effectively used?

Bonus points for tools/techniques to do the same to Explorer shell extensions and/or browser extensions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [xperf to trace pool leaks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/maartenb/archive/2010/12/07/debugging-pool-leaks-with-x-perf.aspx) and [VMMap for shellextension leaks](http://blog.dopus.com/2010/11/new-guide-how-to-find-components.html).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You get bonus points (upvote) for that, though I'm still looking to find out how to do this for drivers.

Comment: ok, I've added a xperf link to trace pool leaks.

Comment: How do you actually use xperf? The linked page uses xperfview however "Xperfview is no longer supported."

Comment: @annanfay check this answer: https://superuser.com/a/949246/174557